# sql workbench index and constraint error when trying to forward engineer

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

When trying to forward engineer my database model, I get the error down below. I know that this question has been answered many times and I have looked through most of them but they have not fixed my problem. Just so this doesn't get marked I will paste the links of the questions I have used as a reference. Below I will put down the error from my `log file`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Forward Engineering MySQL Workbench Error 1064](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52624659/forward-engineering-mysql-workbench-error-1064)

[Forward Engineering in MySQL Workbench outputs error 1064](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52679732/forward-engineering-in-mysql-workbench-outputs-error-1064)

[Forward engineering mysql workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26526572/forward-engineering-mysql-workbench)

[ERROR 1005 MySQL Workbench Forward engineering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23230708/error-1005-mysql-workbench-forward-engineering)

`SQL Workbench V.8.0.12`

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VISIBLE,
  INDEX `id_Department_idx` (`id_Department` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT' at line 12
SQL Code:
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table `hospitaldb`.`Staff`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `hospitaldb`.`Staff` (
          `staff_id` INT NOT NULL,
          `first_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
          `last_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
          `id_Department` INT NULL,
          `title` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
          `id_Hospital` INT NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`staff_id`),
          INDEX `id_Hospital_idx` (`id_Hospital` ASC) VISIBLE,
          INDEX `id_Department_idx` (`id_Department` ASC) VISIBLE,
          CONSTRAINT `id_Hospital`
            FOREIGN KEY (`id_Hospital`)
            REFERENCES `hospitaldb`.`Hospital` (`idHospital`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
          CONSTRAINT `id_Department`
            FOREIGN KEY (`id_Department`)
            REFERENCES `hospitaldb`.`Hospital` (`idHospital`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 7 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VISIBLE,
  INDEX `id_Department_idx` (`id_Department` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT' at line 12
SQL Code:
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table `hospitaldb`.`Staff`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `hospitaldb`.`Staff` (
          `staff_id` INT NOT NULL,
          `first_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
          `last_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
          `id_Department` INT NULL,
          `title` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
          `id_Hospital` INT NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`staff_id`),
          INDEX `id_Hospital_idx` (`id_Hospital` ASC) VISIBLE,
          INDEX `id_Department_idx` (`id_Department` ASC) VISIBLE,
          CONSTRAINT `id_Hospital`
            FOREIGN KEY (`id_Hospital`)
            REFERENCES `hospitaldb`.`Hospital` (`idHospital`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
          CONSTRAINT `id_Department`
            FOREIGN KEY (`id_Department`)
            REFERENCES `hospitaldb`.`Hospital` (`idHospital`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 7 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

Comment: Unless you are using MySQL 8 `VISIBLE` is not valid MySQL

Comment: so should I get rid of the `VISIBLE` and see if it works?

Comment: Yes give that a try

Comment: yeah I did but it comes back when I try to forward engineer

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Version 8.0.12.

Comment: Then `VISIBLE` should work... are you sure that's the MySQL version and not the MySQL workbench version?

Comment: So what is the MySQL version?

Comment: `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.11, for osx10.11 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`